# Could you make me a party themed around Office Space? Greaaaaat

Tags: dnd-4e, party

Inspired by this [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/conversation/office-space).

The iconic quotes and roles of the movie [Office Space](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/quotes) presents conflict between a programmer and his job. Translating the company "initech" into an adventuring party could make for a fun and light-hearted convention game.

My main trouble is figuring out what characters from the show would make for the most engaging party and what 4e races/classes/themes to map them to.

**Which group of characters from Office Space could be made into an effective party of PCs in this adventure and what gimmicks can they be given to evoke their characterization from the movie?**

Comment: Meta: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/sudo-make-me-a-party-are-party-creation-questions-ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

Anne - Tiefling Ardent to represent devilish girlfriend and cheating ways (Leader)

Peter - Human Warlock with fey pact to represent Hypnotism (Striker)

Samir - Shade Rogue to represent his view of the world and roll as main thief (Striker)

Michael - Changling Wizard BladeSinger, because he gets confused for Michael Bolton the singer, and Programming is like being a wizard. (Controller)

Milton - Warforged Barbarian Berzeker, cause well, you know he is. Red, for his stapler. (Defender)

Joanna - Half-elf Bard With Flare, with Monk Dilenete skill cause she likes Kung Fu (Leader)

Answer (score 2):

Some initial thoughts from this 3.x player:
Peter: Fighter
Michael: wizard/sorcerer (because of the virus)
Sameer: I have no ideas.
Joana: I'm seeing a cleric of some good god
Lawrence: Fighter?  Cleric of some wise god?
Smykowski: Bard.  Charisma 3 bard.

As for the corporate structure
bob = the king 
bob = the king's vassal
Bob, bob, bob, bob: various ambassadors, administrators, bureaucrats
Lumberg = the local lord
Milton = the victim

The Stapler = what was stolen from the victim, and the party is sent out to recover.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect example of using the wrong tool for the job. 4e is great for a lot of things, but tales of hilarious haphazardry with staplers and middle management aren't really it's strong suit. I think [Fiasco](http://www.bullypulpitgames.com/games/fiasco/) suits this style of game much better. But that's just my opinion. :)

Comment: And hey, there's even a playset in existence that's already pretty close: http://www.entirelysafeandfun.com/Fiasco-WhiteCollar.pdf